# Merge Text Node after wrap and unwrap jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, word-wrap

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<p> hello every body, to day is a sunny day</p>
```

I have use `wrap()` method to wrap element with `<em>` tag like the following:

```html
<p> hello every body, to day is <em>a sunny day<em></p>
```

When I finished my test, I use `$("em").contents().unwrap()` to unwrap all `<em>` tag:

```
I make a loop for all elements in my page
So I found that
-----hello every body, to day is a----
and 
-----a sunny day-----

are 2 seperated text nodes,
```

How can I use `wrap()` and `unwrap()`, so my text won't be splited like that?

Comment: Cloud you plese post the code of you loop? What do you mean by "all" Elements?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Try unwrapping any `span` tag in a `p` tag. You're left with 3 separate text nodes, visible as different quotes in Chrome dev tools. It makes no difference on the front end, but if you go to highlight something that spans the text nodes, it can't be done.

Comment: I'd not use `wrap()` for this very reason. I guess the reason you are wrapping the text is for highlighting. A better solution is to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` whenever you need to highlight some characters.

Answer (score 1):

This question goes back a while, so my answer may only be of use to people in the future facing similar problems to the OP (as I was myself).

A neat way to re-combine the unwrapped text nodes is by resetting the `innerHtml` of the span's parent element using `$.html()`

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit</span> amet.</p>
```

JS

```
function reset () {
    var parent = $('span').parent();
    $('span').contents().unwrap();
    parent.html(function(i, html) {
       return html;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you cannot use .wrap() and .unwrap() to do what I think you intend to do. .unwrap() calls replaceWith() in jQuery code which eventually calls [.replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild). The replaceChild() method in JS, replaces one DOM child node, with another. The use of .contents() is creating a [text node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247).

This updates the render tree in the browser, which in turn updates the markup you see in a developer tool. The nodes in a render tree are placed on their own lines for the markup... not to be confused with what actually ends up being displayed: since \n is a whitespace character, the text nodes will show in one line on the screen.

If you need the actual text (innerHTML) to not be broken up as textNodes you will have to resort to somewhat drastic, measures:

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         var _childContent = $('em').contents()[0].data,
>             _childIndex = $('p')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('<em>'),
>             _parentText;
>
>         $('em').remove();
>         _parentText = $('p')[0].innerHTML;
>         $('p')[0].innerHTML = _parentText.substr(0, _childIndex) + 
>                               _childContent +
>                               _parentText.substr(_childIndex + 1, _parentText.length);
>     });
> ```

Due to having to take such measures, I would agree with grmmph's comment about if it is an issue of styling, then take the addClass() approach.

However, if what you want is to have all the text between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags appear on one line instead of being treated as textNodes, then the above works (at least in IE 10 when viewed in the developer tool).

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked so long ago, but because an answer hasn't been marked yet, I'll post an answer. I'm not sure if you wanted those text nodes split or not, but both ways can be done like this (run snippets to see it work):

The vanilla Javascript way (found [here](https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/unwrap-a-dom-element-35/)):

```js
function unwrapElement () {
  var el = document.querySelector('em')
  var parent = el.parentNode
  while (el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el)
  parent.removeChild(el)
}
```

```html
<p>Hello every body, to day is <em>a sunny day<em></p>
<button onclick="unwrapElement()">Do unwrap</button>
```

The JQuery way (similar to @StevieP's way):

```js
function unwrapElement() {
  $('em').contents().unwrap()
  $('em').parent().html((i, html) => html) // if you remove this, then the text will be split
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello every body, to day is <em>a sunny day<em></p>
<button onclick="unwrapElement()">Do unwrap</button>
```